# Python code works with print but not return

Tags: python

In the following code, I need to return b so that I can use it in another function. I tried testing to see if `b` would be returned but when I run `def main` and `print(n_boxes)`, it gives me `None`. However if I changed `return b` to `print(b)` and `print(n_boxes)` to `n-boxes`, I get the correct output.

```
  def subsets(a, b, lo):
    hi = len(a)
    subs_2 = []
    if (lo == hi):
      return b
    else:
      c = b[:]
      b.append(a[lo])
      subsets (a, c, lo + 1)
      subsets (a, b, lo + 1)
  def main():
    boxes = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5,6], [6, 6, 9], [3, 8, 4]]
    b = []
    n_boxes = subsets(boxes, b, 0)
    print(n_boxes)
  main()
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I need the values for b. Thanks!

Ok so I want all possible subsets to be returned. The "def subsets" can do that.
With "print b" my output is

```
[]
[[3, 8, 4]]
[[6, 6, 9]]
[[6, 6, 9], [3, 8, 4]]
[[4, 5, 6]]
[[4, 5, 6], [3, 8, 4]]
[[4, 5, 6], [6, 6, 9]]
[[4, 5, 6], [6, 6, 9], [3, 8, 4]]
[[1, 2, 3]]
[[1, 2, 3], [3, 8, 4]]
[[1, 2, 3], [6, 6, 9]]
[[1, 2, 3], [6, 6, 9], [3, 8, 4]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [3, 8, 4]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [6, 6, 9]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [6, 6, 9], [3, 8, 4]]
```

I want to be able to use the above subsets individually. So I am trying to find a way to return the subsets and be able to write a function that will give me subsets of length two.
To clarify, I would be able to write such a function, but I would need the individual subsets first.

Comment: can you add the outputs you got?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `subsets` recursively, but don't return anything in the `else:` branch.

For the `if (lo == hi):` branch you return `b`, but if `lo != hi` you don't return anything at all and thus the return value is `None`, the default. If you wanted something returned for that branch, you need to add a `return` statement there too.

Because `b` is altered in-place, perhaps you just wanted to print `b`? You don't need to return anything either in that case:

```
def subsets(a, b, lo):
    hi = len(a)
    subs_2 = []
    if lo != hi:
        c = b[:]
        b.append(a[lo])
        subsets (a, c, lo + 1)
        subsets (a, b, lo + 1)

def main():
    boxes = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5,6], [6, 6, 9], [3, 8, 4]]
    b = []
    subsets(boxes, b, 0)
    print(b)

main()
```

Note that the code ignores `subs_2` entirely, you could just as well remove that line. `c` is also ignored, as altered by the recursive call, is also ignored. The above code copies all sublists in `boxes` unaltered to `b`.

I **suspect** you wanted a different outcome, but you didn't give us any indication as to what the code is *supposed* to do.

Comment: In the function subsets, I am trying get all possible outputs.